# Reverse proxy Nginx with multiple docker containers

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I'm setting up nginx as a reverse proxy for several docker containers. It is only available from the local network on 192.168.1.2. Because subdomains aren't possible in combination with an IP, I'd like all docker containers on a separate sub folder, so 192.168.1.2/nextcloud, etc etc.

The issue starts with Nextcloud. The URL is automatically rewritten to 192.168.1.2/login, which results in a 404. How do i fix this?

```
server {
  listen                443 ssl http2;
  server_name           192.168.1.2;
  include               /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl-params.conf;
  location ~/nextcloud {
    proxy_pass                       http://nextcloud:80;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host            $host;
  } 
  location ~/bookstack {
    proxy_pass                       http://bookstack:80;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host            $host;
  }
}
```

Comment: Configure the baseurl of nextcloud properly.

Comment: All your applications should support configuring base URLs. If some application doesn't support it, then you should set up a local DNS and use subdomains.

Comment: You can use [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directive to rewrite a hostname in HTTP 30x redirections `Location` header. However correct app setup for base URL is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Nextcloud allows you to set base URL with "overwritewebroot" option (https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/13.0.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html#proxy-configurations) but as already pointed out, all of your applications must support similar option.

Also don't forget that you are not restricted to subdomains, you can use full domain name or a different IP in your case. This isn't the best way to handle things but you can consider assigning several IPs to the network interface of your host and that should allow you to separate sockets.